# How do I split the $0 variable to find directory and relative paths in bash?

Tags: bash, parameter

The $0 variable contains the path info of the script.

- How can I change the path info to absolute path? I mean how to process ~, ., .. or similar?
- How can I split the path info into directory and file name?

I could use python/perl for this, but I want to use bash if possible.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? btw. calling a script with ~/foo.sh will expand ~ into my home directory for $0 with my bash version (GNU bash, version 4.1.5(2)-release-(x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu))

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to process things like `~`, the shell does it for you. That's why you can pass `~/filename` to any script or program and it works -- all those programs don't handle `~` themselves, your shell converts the argument to `/home/username/filename` and passes that to the program instead:

```
$ echo ~/filename
/home/mrozekma/filename
```

If you need a canonical filename (one that doesn't include things like `..`), use `realpath` (thanks [Neil](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1620/neil-mayhew)):

```
$ realpath ~/../filename
/home/filename
```

---

As for splitting the path into directory name and filename, use `dirname` and `basename`:

```
$ dirname /foo/bar/baz
/foo/bar

$ basename /foo/bar/baz
baz
```

Comment: I think you mean realpath, not readlink. readlink won't work in the common situation, ie when the link uses a relative path and you are not in the same dir as the link.

Comment: @Neil `realpath` is better, but `readlink` seems to work when I try it; do you know of an example where it fails?

Comment: `cd /tmp; touch foo; ln -s foo bar; cd; readlink /tmp/bar`. This returns `foo` and `realpath` returns `/tmp/foo`, which is what you want.

Comment: @Neil, @Michael: `readlink -f` (note `-f`) is almost equivalent to `realpath`, and it's more portable: `readlink -f` in GNU coreutils and exists on a few other systems as well; `realpath` is packaged separately and may not be installed (e.g. only 5 not-that-common packages depend on it in Ubuntu 10.04 or Debian lenny).

Comment: @Gilles: good point. Thanks for the reminder about realpath -f.

Comment: @Gilles: Unfortunately, readlink on Mac uses -f for something completely different, so this is not so portable as I would like. I have therefore written my own C utility wrapper for realpath(3) that I use on Mac so I can write portable scripts that use realpath.

Comment: @Gilles What about `readlink -e`? Does Mac have that option to test if all components exist? If testing `$0`, we already know it exists.

Comment: @toxalot [OSX `readlink`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/readlink.1.html) doesn't have `-e`.

Answer (score 5):

Using dirname and basename like mentioned by Michael should be the safest way to get what you want.

Anyway if you really want to do this with "bash only tools" you could use parameter substitution:

```
echo `basename $PWD`        # Basename of current working directory.
echo "${PWD##*/}"           # Basename of current working directory.
echo
echo `basename $0`          # Name of script.
echo $0                     # Name of script.
echo "${0##*/}"             # Name of script.
echo
filename=test.data
echo "${filename##*.}"      # data
                            # Extension of filename.
```

This example is directly taken from the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PSOREX1) which is worth a look.

The explanation is pretty simple:

> ${var#Pattern} Remove from $var the
>   shortest part of $Pattern that matches
>   the front end of $var. ${var##Pattern}
>   Remove from $var the longest part of
>   $Pattern that matches the front end of
>   $var.

Look at the pattern like some regex and the `#` or `##` as some kind of greedy/non-greedy modifier.

This might become useful if you will have to do some more complicated extractions of a paths part.

Comment: Beware when using `${...##...}` and friends rather than `dirname` and `basename` that they don't work in all cases. For example both `${0##*/}` and `${0%/*}` expand to the same as `$0` if `$0` doesn't contain a `/`.

Comment: @Gilles I understand why `${0%/*}` is not a good alternative to `dirname`. However, what's wrong with using `${0##*/}` instead of `basename`?

Comment: @toxalot For this one, the only problem is when `$0` is a directory name with a trailing `/`. But I regret my advice, because `dirname` doesn't do any better.

Answer (score 2):

`realpath` is a command which tells you the real path (removes .. and symbolic links etc.)

It is standard with FreeBSD. According to this discussion it's also available for Linux:

http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/89294-geting-real-path.html

That discussion also offers a bash solution:

```
$ bash -c "cd /foo/../bar/ ; pwd"
```

Comment: Exactly, something like this usually works:  MYDIR="$(cd $(dirname "$0"); pwd)"