# How to add a modular bash script to `bin`?

Tags: shell-script, compiling, module

I have a bash script that uses `source` to make the script more modular. Here's how it would look copied into a user's `bin` directory:

```
/bin
    modules/
        script-1
        script-2
        script-3
        script-4
        script-5
    main-app
```

However, this doesn't work if you want to execute `main-app` from a directory other than your `bin` directory. Is there a way to use `source ./modules/script-x` in `main-app` so that I can source these files properly? Or should I be converting `main-app` into one file? If I do need to, should I do this manually or is there some kinda "compiler" I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`$0`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) positional parameter and [`dirname`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo running "$(dirname "$0")/$(basename "$0")"
source "$(dirname "$0")/modules/script-1"
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine, thank you!

Comment: @APixelVisuals If your directories or file names contain spaces or commas or ... you need to quote as in the [latest edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/518016/revisions)

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but thank you for pointing this out. In this case though, I already had added them :P

Answer (score 1):

You have to extract real path of your script, and then source your modules:

```
#!/bin/bash

FULLPATH_OF_MAIN=`realpath $BASH_SOURCE`
SOURCEDIR=`dirname ${FULLPATH_OF_MAIN}`

source ${SOURCEDIR}/modules/script-x
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a dot (`.`) in your directories makes them relative to the dot "this directory" (pwd).

If you don't mind static directories (relative to the user dir (~)) you could use:

```
source ~/bin/modules/script-x     # or equivalent: . ~/bin/modules/script-x
```

If you need directories relative to the directory where main-app was started (any directory) you could use (in bash):

```
source "${BASH_SOURCE%/*}/modules/script-x"
```

Or, in many shells:

```
source "$(basename "$0")/modules/script-x"
```

That `$0` will work assuming the way in which the main-app was called will make the name given listed by ps contain the correct path of the file. That is not always the case:

```
$ exec -atestname /bin/bash
$ echo "$0"
testname
```

If your directory may contain links and you need the canonical path (no links or relative (..) names used) then use:

```
source "$(basename "$(readlink -f -- "$BASH_SOURCE")" )/modules/script-x"
```

Or replace `"$BASH_SOURCE"` with `"$0"` (if needed).

Note: that in [some corner cases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1766/265604) you actually may need to use `realpath` instead of `readlink -f`

Or just `cd` to the correct directory (avoid readlink or realpath):

```
source "$( cd "${BASH_SOURCE%/*}" > /dev/null && pwd )/modules/script-x"
```

Comment: Wow!  I know I know nothing now...  **+1 ;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Some more corner cases added :-) . Hope this helps.